Island Traveling question
In a faraway ocean, there is a country consisting of many islands. A person can travel from one island to
another only by airplane. Fortunately, all airplane routes operate in both directions.
The country’s largest island, Grand Goddess, has airplane routes to exactly 21 other islands. Its smallest
island, Forgotten Rock, has an airplane route to only one other island. Each of the country’s remaining
islands has airplane routes to exactly 12 other islands. (For avoidance of doubt, all of the islands mentioned
here are parts of the same country. No international travel is included!)
Prove that it is possible to fly from Grand Goddess to Forgotten Rock (possibly using connecting flights).
I thought I could contradict the problem itself, as I thought I found a way to isolate Forgotten Rock, but when reviewing I noticed a problem. I tried to create a tree of islands starting with forgotten rock and using minimal amounts of islands, but it only got me into an infinite loop. I tried the same with Grand Goddess, but also failed. I am in need of help.(also, I don't know what to tag this as)

I suggest: rephrase this as a problem in graph theory (each island is a node, each plane route is an edge).  If nothing else, this will make it easier for others to read.

Are you familiar with the so-called handshaking lemma?

You have a graph, where vertices are islands and edges are (direct) airlines. Its vertices have the following degrees: $21$, $1$, and all the others are $12$.
Use the fact that in any graph there is even number of vertices of odd degree. It is a corollary from the fact that the sum of degrees of all the vertices of a graph is twice the number of its edges. The last fact is obvious since every edge “adds” $1$ to two vertices’ degrees, or $2$ to the sum of all degrees.
Suppose there is no path from the vertex of degree $21$ to the vertex of degree $1$. Then consider the graph consisting of the vertex of degree $21$ and all the vertices reachable from it.
What can you say about this graph?

So you mean I can use proof by contradiction and say that grand goddess was isolated, but that leaves me with a graph with an odd number of odd degrees?

@Mike Yes. If Grand Goddess is isolated from Forgotten Rock, we get a contradiction.
